# dynamics customer insights check table imported on dynamics crm

Tags: datatables, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I'm importing data into "Dynamics Customer Insights data" using connectors. I can see the imported tables only in "Dynamics Customer Insights data". Is there a way to take this table in the CRM or in other ways, or are those tables only visible in Dynamics Customer Insights data?